# Get Sum using php and SQL is date is same

Tags: php, mysql, sql, select, sum

I have a db structure as follows:

```
Date         Morning    Evening Qty(Ltr)  Total 
13-May-2015   101         10                111 
15-May-2015   10          1.25              11.25   
15-May-2015   10          2.25              12.25   
15-May-2015   101         10                111 
16-May-2015   10          1.25             11.25    
16-May-2015   10          2.25             12.25    
17-May-2015   10          2.25             12.25
```

What I want is to create a new table in which the data with the same date should be in one row only, means duplicate dates should be added. How can I do this ?

I want the result

```
Date         Morning    Evening Qty(Ltr)  Total 
13-May-2015   101         10                111 
15-May-2015   121         13.5            134.5
16-May-2015   20          3.5               23.5
17-May-2015   10          2.25             12.25
```

Comment: duplicate dates should be added or should not ???

Comment: Show the result you want. And also some code you tried.

Comment: should be added actually this is for different users

Comment: @lord_linus And where is your effort?

Answer (score 5):

You are looking for a `group by` clause:

```
SELECT   `date`, SUM(morning), SUM(evening), SUM(total)
FROM     mytable
GROUP BY `date`
```

Comment: morning and evening should also have SUM

Comment: @AmirRahimiFarahani You are correct, I misread the OP. Fixed. Thanks for noticing!

Answer (score 2):

You can grab the data using

```
SELECT SUM(Morning) as Morning, SUM(EveningQty) as EveningQty, SUM(Total) as Total 
FROM table
WHERE Date = '$date'
```

So putting in `15-May-2015` for `$date` will give you 121, 13.50, 134.50

Comment: but dont you think it would be so lengthy

Comment: Try it, that's the only way to find out.

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT `Date`, 
       SUM(Morning) AS Morning, 
       SUM(EveningQty) AS EveningQty, 
       SUM(Morning + EveningQty) AS Total
  FROM SomeTable
  GROUP BY `Date`
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to put that data into a new table:

```
INSERT INTO Table1_Sum
(Date, Morning, EveningQty, Total)
SELECT Date, SUM(Morning), SUM(EveningQty), SUM(Total)
FROM Table1
GROUP BY Date
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this code will help you

```
INSERT INTO YOUR_NEW_TABLE (`date`, morning, evening, total ) 
SELECT date, sum(`morning`), sum(`evening`), sum(`Total`)
FROM YOUR_OLD_TABLE group by date
```